Discord screen sharing doesn't work
Every time I try to use Discord screen sharing on Ubuntu 24.04 on my desktop, it gets stuck at the screen selection window without letting me do anything but close the Discord screen share window. My laptop has the same OS, but it doesn't have the same problem.

